# Rails - Count loop with Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a rails app where I often need to generate xls files with several values.
To do so I load customers orders in my controller (`valid` is just a custom scope)

```
@orders = Order.valid.order('id DESC')
```

In my view, I want to count meals for each orders with different scopes (i removed all xml tags, which are not interesting here):

```
<% @orders.each do |order| %>
  <%= order.meals.count %>
  <%= order.meals.meat.count %>
  <%= order.meals.fish.count %>
  <%= order.meals.drink.count %>
  <%= order.meals.dessert.count %>
<% end %>
```

My problem is that this generates a very large number of SQL requests.

I tried to preload meals like this:

```
@orders = Order.valid.order('id DESC').preload(:meals)
```

But count requests keep being generated

I also found an old gem: `preload_count` to do this, but it doesn't works with rails 4.

Is there a way to optimize my requests ?

**EDIT**

After many tries and help from Andrey Deineko, my request turned into this:

```
Order.includes(:meals).valid.order('id DESC').references(:meals)
```

Then i realized it may come from meal types which are in another table in my DB

```
Order.eager_load(meals: :type).valid.order('orders.id DESC').references(:meals)
```

But still, here are my db requests:

```
(0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "meals" INNER JOIN "meals_orders" ON "meals"."id" = "meals_orders"."meal_id" WHERE "meals_orders"."order_id" = $1  [["order_id", 1044]]
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "meals" INNER JOIN "meals_orders" ON "meals"."id" = "meals_orders"."meal_id" WHERE "meals_orders"."order_id" = $1  [["order_id", 1044]]
   (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "meals" INNER JOIN "types" ON "types"."id" = "meals"."type_id" INNER JOIN "meals_orders" ON "meals"."id" = "meals_orders"."meal_id" WHERE "meals_orders"."order_id" = $1 AND "types"."name" = $2  [["order_id", 1044], ["name", "meat"]]
   (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "meals" INNER JOIN "types" ON "types"."id" = "meals"."type_id" INNER JOIN "meals_orders" ON "meals"."id" = "meals_orders"."meal_id" WHERE "meals_orders"."order_id" = $1 AND "types"."name" = $2  [["order_id", 1044], ["name", "meat"]]
   (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "meals" INNER JOIN "types" ON "types"."id" = "meals"."type_id" INNER JOIN "meals_orders" ON "meals"."id" = "meals_orders"."meal_id" WHERE "meals_orders"."order_id" = $1 AND "types"."name" = $2  [["order_id", 1044], ["name", "fish"]]
   (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "meals" INNER JOIN "types" ON "types"."id" = "meals"."type_id" INNER JOIN "meals_orders" ON "meals"."id" = "meals_orders"."meal_id" WHERE "meals_orders"."order_id" = $1 AND "types"."name" = $2  [["order_id", 1044], ["name", "fish"]]
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "meals" INNER JOIN "types" ON "types"."id" = "meals"."type_id" INNER JOIN "meals_orders" ON "meals"."id" = "meals_orders"."meal_id" WHERE "meals_orders"."order_id" = $1 AND "types"."name" = $2  [["order_id", 1044], ["name", "drink"]]
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "meals" INNER JOIN "types" ON "types"."id" = "meals"."type_id" INNER JOIN "meals_orders" ON "meals"."id" = "meals_orders"."meal_id" WHERE "meals_orders"."order_id" = $1 AND "types"."name" = $2  [["order_id", 1044], ["name", "drink"]]
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "meals" INNER JOIN "types" ON "types"."id" = "meals"."type_id" INNER JOIN "meals_orders" ON "meals"."id" = "meals_orders"."meal_id" WHERE "meals_orders"."order_id" = $1 AND "types"."name" = $2  [["order_id", 1044], ["name", "dessert"]]
```

Comment: When iterating through collections, be sure to use `find_each`, which is batched, instead of `each` to prevent loading a potentially massive result set into memory.

Comment: Thanks, I changed this in my code, but it doesn't answer my question :/

Comment: @Shrolox did you find a solution to this problem? The only other thing i can think of is caching the count in a column, in your orders table.

Comment: I don't remember but since I didn't post any solution, I think I went for a workaround like the one you suggested

Answer (score 1):

go with

```
@orders = Order.includes(:meals).valid.order('id DESC')
```

if you want to have only orders with meals (no orders, where meal is `nil`) go with:

```
@orders = Order.joins(:meals).valid.order('id DESC')
```

Have a read about [AR querying](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html).

Comment: Tried this, but AR still generates a request to get the count. it's eager_loading counts that i want. Or maybe i misunderstood you

Comment: Might by my misunderstanding. Could you try `Order.includes(:meals).valid.order('id DESC').references(:meals)`?

Comment: Thanks. I tried this, but count requests are still firing. As meal scopes refers to another database (Types) i tried to include these with a eager load. I'll update my post to show you.

Answer (score 0):

If your models have a has_many belongs_to relationship you can use includes to eager load the associations. [This](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/improving-the-performance-of-your-rails-app-with-eager-loading--cms-25018) is a good article on eager loading.

Comment: Thanks. I tried eager_loading, but i can't succeed in preloading counts in only one request.